# Spark Join for Each Item in List

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataset like

```
+----------+-------+----+---+--------------+
|        _1|     _2|  _3| _4|            _5|
+----------+-------+----+---+--------------+
|      null|1111111|null| 15|       [98765]|
|      null|2222222|null| 16|[97008, 98765]|
|6436334664|3333333|null| 15|       [97008]|
|2356242642|4444444|null| 11|       [97008]|
+----------+-------+----+---+--------------+
```

Where the the fifth column is a list of zipcodes associated to that row. I have another table that has unique rows for each zipcode and a corresponding longitude and latitude. I want to create a table like

```
+----------+-------+----+---+--------------+-----------------------------------
|        _1|     _2|  _3| _4|            _5|                                _6|
+----------+-------+----+---+--------------+----------------------------------+
|3572893528|1111111|null| 15|       [98765]| [(54.12,-80.53)]                 |
|5325232523|2222222|null| 16|[98765, 97008]| [(54.12,-80.53), (44.12,-75.11)] |
|6436334664|3333333|null| 15|       [97008]| [(54.12,-80.53)]                 | 
|2356242642|4444444|null| 11|       [97008]| [(54.12,-80.53)]                 |
+----------+-------+----+---+--------------+----------------------------------+
```

where the sixth column is the coordinates for the zips in the sequence of the fifth column.

I have tried to just filter the zipcode table everytime I need coordinates but I get a NPE, I think because of similar reasons detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539391/dataframe-filter-gives-nullpointerexception) question. If I try to collect the zipcode table before filtering it I run out of memory.

I am using Scala and I got the original Dataset using Spark SQL in a Spark job. Any solutions would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is your example a bit miss-leading or is this what you really want? Because you are relating `98765` with `(54.12,-80.53)` and `(44.12,-75.11)` - at first two rows? It has to be one on one mapping right? Meaning that `98765` is related with `(54.12,-80.53)` and `97008` with `(44.12,-75.11)`?

Comment: @vilalabinot Thank you for clarifying, that is what I meant, the mapping is 1 to 1. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume (the comment on your question holds true and) we have have two datasets (simplifying your example), `ds` and `ds2`, respectively:

```
+---+--------------+
|_1 |_2            |
+---+--------------+
|15 |[98765]       |
|16 |[97008, 98765]|
|15 |[97008]       |
|15 |[97008]       |
+---+--------------+
```

```
+-----+---------------+
|_2   |_3             |
+-----+---------------+
|98765|{54.12, -80.53}|
|97008|{44.12, -75.11}|
+-----+---------------+
```

The idea is to create a unique ID (so we can join later), `explode` the dataset, then `join` to get the coordinates per unique ID, finally join the tables again.

Creating a unique ID:

```
ds = ds.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Then create the mapping table that contains `id` and your zip codes:

```
val map = ds
  .withColumn("_2", explode(col("_2")))
  .join(ds2, Seq("_2"), "left")
  .groupBy("id").agg(collect_set(col("_3")))
```

Finally join back on the main table:

```
ds = ds.join(map, Seq("id"))
```

Final output:

```
+---+--------------+----------------------------------+
|_1 |_2            |collect_set(_3)                   |
+---+--------------+----------------------------------+
|15 |[98765]       |[{54.12, -80.53}]                 |
|16 |[97008, 98765]|[{54.12, -80.53}, {44.12, -75.11}]|
|15 |[97008]       |[{44.12, -75.11}]                 |
|15 |[97008]       |[{44.12, -75.11}]                 |
+---+--------------+----------------------------------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: This method works great, but the ordering of the zipcodes to coordinates do not match.

Comment: I was afraid of this case, let me try and fix that

Comment: I don't think there is a lot you can do, except saving `key` itself, as so:

`ds2 = ds2.withColumn("_3", struct("_2", "_3"))`, then you collected set would look like:

`[{98765, {54.12, -80.53}}, {97008, {44.12, -75.11}}]`